# Do I have too many WPF layers here?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I think I'm on my way to finally grokking MVVM. I was just looking at a situation I found myself in and I'm wondering if I should combine two of my layers. I currently have a structure like this:

1. Domain models (in a separate .net project)
2. WPF-side "models" which wrap domain models and track dirty state
3. WPF ViewModels
4. Views

The question is whether I should combine 2 and 3. Right now #2 is the layer that gets passed around by my mediator to facilitate all the viewmodels knowing what document is currently opened. But I think my code for 2 and 3 is too similar and is unnecessary duplication at this point.

Example:

```
// in layer 2, class ProjectDocument
// Project is an instance of the domain model
public string Name
{
    get { return Project.Name; }
    set
    {
        if (Project.Name == value) return;
        Project.Name = value;
        Dirty = true;
    }
}

// in layer 3, class ProjectSettingsViewModel
// _project is a ProjectDocument
public string Name
{
    get { return _project.Name; }
    set
    {
        _project.Name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

Seeing that struck me as unnecessary. So should I combine them? On one hand, it would remove a lot of redundant code and I'd have fewer places to update when I change things. On the other, I might be giving one class too much responsibility, and also it seems inappropriate for an actual ViewModel to be passed around to other VMs via my mediator. The `ProjectSettingsViewModel` wouldn't use even half of the fields on `ProjectDocument` if they were combined.

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way. Is there a better way to reduce the duplication while still keeping the responsibilities separate?

Answer (score 0):

I have a master viewmodel that handles application states like which document/tab/window is open and I have an ISettingssService for other global needs.  Passing one viewmodel to another is discouraged and you might want to think about creating am iSettings service that can be injected into the viewmodels, then the viewmodels can interact with "global" settings but the viewmodels are still decoupled because they do not depend on another viewmodel.

So, I would not combine them.  Either I would have a dictionary of documents that can be open in the master viewmodel with a current open doc property or move this logic to a service/interface that gets used by each viewmodel.

Hope this helps.